# Using a stress-energy tensor in linearized Einstein equations

Tags: general-relativity, calculus, cosmic-string

I am using a known stress-energy tensor to try to find $h_{\mu\nu}$, the small deviations from flat space in the linearized Einstein formalism. In harmonic gauge,
$$
\square h_{\mu\nu}=-16\pi GT_{\mu\nu}+8\pi G\eta_{\mu\nu}T^{\alpha}_{\alpha}.
$$
For the stress energy tensor $T_{\mu}^{\nu}=\mu\delta (x)\delta (y)\mathrm{diag(}1,0,0,1\mathrm{)}$, the right hand side should simplify to $-16\pi G\mu\delta (x)\delta (y)\mathrm{diag(}0,1,1,0\mathrm{)}$. It says in chapter 7.1 [here](https://inspirehep.net/literature/1384873) that this is solved by $$
h_{11}=h_{22}=8G\mu\ln\bigg(\frac{r}{r_0}\bigg)
$$ where $r^2=x^2+y^2$ and $r_0$ is a constant of integration (the other terms in $h_{\mu\nu}$ vanish). How do I work backwards from the stress-energy tensor to get this? Plugging this solution into Mathematica and taking the Laplacian of it yields
$$
16G\mu\bigg(\frac{1-r^2}{r^2}\bigg)
$$
for the right hand side which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: I think you're taking the Laplacian wrong in Mathematica. `Simplify[Laplacian[8 G mu Log[r/r0], {r, theta, z}, "Cylindrical"]]` yields `0` (which is, of course, correct everywhere except $r = 0$.)

Answer (score 0):

Convert to cylindrical coordinates - a natural symmetry for the problem, then integrate, arguing away functional dependence on t, theta and z. Recall that the arguments of Delta functions transform according to a Jacobian rule.